# How to scroll inside Fancybox overlay?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, fancybox

I am using jQuery Fancybox (v2.1.5) to open forms in modal boxes. I would like to scroll to the first invalid field after clicking on the submit button. I have already set up a code base which deals with the validation of the form and the other stuff I need. Everything seems to work fine except the scrolling part.

It seems trivial but I can't get it to work. I have set up a simplified example of what I would like to achieve.

Here is the code:

### HTML

```html
<a class="fancybox" href="#modalform">Open modal form</a>

<form id="modalform">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label id="email-label" for="email">Email</label>
            <input id="email" type="text" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <label id="password-label" for="password">Password</label>
            <input id="password" type="password" />
        </li>
    </ul>

    <input type="submit" value="Log In" />
</form>
```

### CSS

```css
#modalform {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px; height: 1000px;
}

ul li:not(:first-child) {
    margin-top: 1em;
}

label {
    display: block;
}

input {
    width: 100%; height: 2em;
}

input[type="submit"] {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; left: 0;
}
```

### JavaScript (using jQuery 1.x)

```js
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
    autoResize: false,
    fitToView: false
});

$('input[type="submit"]').click(function () {
    $('input:not([type="submit"])').each(function () {
        var targetId = $(this).attr('id') + '-label';

        if ($(this).val().trim() === '') {
            // TODO: scroll to #targetId
            // Doesn't work (obviously?), but shows what I'm trying to achieve
            $(document).scrollTop($('#' + targetId).offset().top);
            // Note: document may not be the correct element to select,
            // but it doesn't work either with the other elements I've tested

            return false;
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

This example is on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eYtme/.

Can you make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('.fancybox-overlay')` is what you want to select instead of `document`.

```
$('.fancybox-overlay').scrollTop($('#' + targetId).offset().top);
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for. For those who want to see the complete code, here it is: [http://jsfiddle.net/eYtme/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/eYtme/1/).